# Perl eval strange case

Tags: perl

Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Perl 5.14.2

we have a strange bug in production.
it is 100% reproduced and is fixed by 
making additional block-eval over it.

Reproduced yet bug in these situations:

1) `eval { <some-code>; <die or Carp::confess>; }`

die or Carp::confess terminate process (eval doesn't help)

so making 
this like: 
`eval { eval { <some-code>; <die or Carp::confess>; } $@ && die $@; }` 
helps

2) 
`our %ENV` resets %ENV
so making `eval { our %ENV; }` helps

I suspect this strange case is because of some
 our xs-modules, but can't find the reason.

Will appreciate any suggestions or hints

I can't post any code, cause it is reproduced deeply in codebase.
Simple 1-liners don't reproduce it.

Also I noticed that problem is fixed by not including some xs-modules.

P.S. I suppose this question is more for 
interaction between perl-internals and perl-xs, than pure-perl

Comment: Make a minimal test-case and post it here. Challenge: as few lines as possible to reproduce the error.

Comment: Does your program have its own `__DIE__` handler?

Comment: If it's 100% reproduceable, why aren't producing the code to reproduce it?!

Answer (score 4):

A `local` directly inside an `eval` is restored outside. If the localized variable is magical and it's setter dies, you could see that behaviour.

```
perl -MVariable::Magic=cast,wizard -le'
   cast $x, wizard(
      set => sub {
         print "store ${$_[0]}";
         die "leaked\n" if $i++ && ${$_[0]} == 123;
      },
   );
   $x = 123; eval { local $x = 456; die "meow\n"; 1 } or print("caught");
'
```

```
store 123
store
store 456
store 123
leaked
```

Tied variables are magical, so the following produces the same output:

```
perl -MTie::Scalar -le'
   @ISA=Tie::StdScalar::;
   sub STORE {
      print "store $_[1]";
      die "leaked\n" if $i++ && $_[1] == 123;
      return shift->SUPER::STORE(@_);
   }
   tie $x, __PACKAGE__;
   $x = 123; eval { local $x = 456; die "meow\n"; 1 } or print("caught");
'
```

Adding an extra scope inside the `eval` solves the problem.

```
$x = 123; eval { { local $x = 456; } 1 } or print("caught");
```

Comment: Note that `%ENV` and its elements are magical.